# Trying to switch information from popup to sidebar

Tags: leaflet, popup, html

How can I move the information from a popup to a sidebar? On the cluster click I don't want a popup to show up, instead I want the information to be shown in a sidebar.

With the polygon layer I could manage it but when I work with the clustering I cannot find a way to do so.

This is my css:

```css
        .sidebar {
            width: 10%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            background-color: #c3c3c3;
            font-family: "Arial", Arial, serif;
            z-index: 1000;

        }
```

```html
This the html part

    <div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            -- Click the point on map to fill the data --
            <br>
            <b>Nummer:</b>
            <div class="nummer"></div>
            <b>Name:</b>
            <div class="name"></div>

        </div><br>
    </div>
```

And here the javascript

```js
        //boundaries frankfurt
        var ffm =
            "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=cite:ffm&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=epsg:4326";
        $.getJSON(ffm).then((res) => {
            var layer = L.geoJson(res, {
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    layer.on('click', function (e) {
                        $(".nummer").html(feature.properties.sttlnr);
                        $(".name").html(feature.properties.sttlname);
                        ;
                    })
                },
                style: poly,
            }).addTo(map);

            map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
        });


        var dc =
            "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=cite:dc_av_current&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=epsg:4326";

        //style marker, der einzelne Punkt
        const geojsonMarkerOptions = {
            radius: 8,
            fillColor: "#ff7800",
            color: "#000",
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
        };

        const markers = new L.markerClusterGroup({
            spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false,
            showCoverageOnHover: false,
            zoomToBoundsOnClick: false,
            doubleClickZoom: false,
            disableClusteringAtZoom: 13
        });

        //get Children from Point Feature
        markers.on('clusterclick', function (evt) {
            var clusterMarkers = evt.layer.getAllChildMarkers();
            var popupContent =
                '<h4 class = "text-primary">Information</h4>' +
                '<div class="container"><table class="table table-striped">' +
                '<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Stromverbrauch</th><th>IT</th><th>PUE</th><th>Detaillierte Infos</th></tr></thead>' +
                '<tbody>';
            clusterMarkers.forEach(function (marker) {
                popupContent +=
                    '<tr><td>' + marker.feature.properties.dc_name +
                    '</td><td>' + marker.feature.properties.gesamt +
                    '</td><td>' + marker.feature.properties.gesamt_it +
                    '</td><td>' + marker.feature.properties.pue +
                    '</td><td>' + '<a href="http://www.google.com">weitere Infos</a>' +
                    // '</td><td>' + '<button type="submit" ion-button clear round (click)="openPosting()">niceButton</button>'+ 
                    '</td> </tr>';
            });

            popupContent += '</tbody></table></div>';
            var popup = L.popup()
                .setLatLng(evt.latlng)
                .setContent(popupContent)
                .openOn(map);
        });

        //load JSON
        $.getJSON(dc).then((res) => {
            var layer = L.geoJson(res, {
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    const popupContent =
                        '<h4 class = "text-primary">Information</h4>' +
                        '<div class="container"><table class="table table-striped">' +
                        '<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Stromverbrauch</th><th>IT</th></tr></thead>' +
                        '<tbody>' +
                        '<tr><td>' + feature.properties.dc_name + '</td><td>' + feature.properties.gesamt + '</td><td>' + feature.properties.gesamt_it + '</td></tr>' +
                        '</tbody></table></div>';
                    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
                },
                pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
                }
            }).addTo(markers);
            markers.addTo(map);
            map.fitBounds(markers.getBound());
        });
```

Would it be a solution to change the var popup into a sidebar?

Answer (score 2):

After creating popup content, instead of opening popup, you just have to put content in sidebar `div`. To reference it, the best way would be to assign `id` attribute to it. You can also reference it by class, but then you must have only one element with this class.

So instead of opening popup

```
var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng(evt.latlng)
    .setContent(popupContent)
    .openOn(map);
```

content is put into `innerHTML` property of sidenav div:

```
var sidenavCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('sidenav');
sidenavCollection[0].innerHTML = popupContent;
```

This is not really a GIS related question, but purely HTML/JS related one, so in the future please post such question on StackOverflow site.